# python script in linux shell that checks if a command line writes into file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a python script that print output into the screen (linux shell), and I'm printing it with colors.
Is there a way to know if the output goes into a file or not?

Example:

```
script.py parms
```

this gives me good colored output in the shell

Now if I do this:

```
script.py parms > output.txt
```

when I open the file I see weird ASCII characters (the colors values), I've tried to open it in a few text editors (kate, gedit).

I want to do something like:

```
if goesIntoFile:
  print in black
else:
  print in color
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`isatty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty) on your `stdout` to check if the standard output is a `tty` (terminal) device, or a file.

Check this `script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.stdout.isatty()
```

When run:

```
$ python script.py
True
$ python script.py | cat
False
```

Also, you might want to check some of the color-output libraries which handle this for you, for example [crayons](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crayons) uses the `isatty` approach above.

Comment: `print sys.stdout.isatty()` works better.  It helps to call the function.